# How to make an application which can take screenshot of whole screen of android device programatically?

Tags: android, screen-scraping, screenshot, video-capture, screen-capture

I want to make an application which can take screenshot of whole screen of android device programatically.

I have done some R & D but it suggest that there is only way to take screenshot on rooted devices only or devices higher that API level 4.0 allows access to achieve this.

There are already some paid application which allows to take screenshot on unrooted devices also.

So, it would be great if some one suggest me how to do it on devices which are not rooted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently did something similar to use for sharing with social media. Here is the code that allowed my screen shot to be stored on sd card and used later for whatever your needs are:

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Image;   

// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when you need to access use something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is mCurrentUrlMask?

Comment: That is the problem how can I get view of complete android device screen.

Comment: That is the problem how can I get view of complete android device screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SDK, you can only take a screenshot of your root view (and all of its children,) this means: your views only. Dialogs, toasts, keyboard, spinners and status bar will not be taken, as they do not share the same view tree.

There are some apps on the Play store, but they are sure not cross platform. Using rooted devices, you can use the ASL (Android Screenshot Library) to grab screenshots via the /dev/graphics/fb0 framebuffer. This will work well and will produce grabs similar to ddms. Video hardware overlays will be left black.

I haven't reverse-engineered those apps you mention, but I trust they recognize which device you are using, then send the keys that will take the screenshot (say volume + down) and then watch for new files on the sdcard. You can see they take time to grab a screenshot.

TestFairy (http://www.testfairy.com) grabs the entire screen of your app, including opengl surface views, toasts and dialogs. It does this via instrumentation, and it does this automatically.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve via Open GL? As I am new to it, I don't have perfect idea about it.

Comment: With OpenGL, you can receive the pixels via glReadPixels. Unfortunately, if you have other views on top of this OpenGL layer, you will have to do the mixing yourself, as View.draw will keep the GL views black. So it's quite easy to do one or the other. As I said, both ASL and TestFairy solve this. One requires root and the other doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public void shareit()
    {
        View view =  findViewById(R.id.layout);//ur layout id
        view.getRootView();
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
        {
            picDir  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myPic");
            if (!picDir.exists())
            {
                picDir.mkdir();
            }
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
//          Date date = new Date();
            String fileName = "mylove" + ".jpg";
            picFile = new File(picDir + "/" + fileName);
            try 
            {
                picFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream picOut = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), (int)(bitmap.getHeight()/1.2));
                boolean saved = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, picOut);
                if (saved) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved to your device Pictures "+ "directory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else 
                {
                    //Error
                }
                picOut.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            view.destroyDrawingCache();
        } else {
            //Error

        }

    }
```